# Impact of using a CDN Proxy (like Incapsula or Cloudlfare) with numerous websites

Tags: seo, ip-address, cdn, local-seo

We have a network of something like 70 websites. We have one IP by website for SEO reason. We are planning to move to CDN service like Cloudflare, Incapsula or Google PageSpeed Service to speed up our websites.

Our concern is that if we do that, it might impact negatively our SEO as our websites are going the same IPs.

What do you think?

Comment: All of these sites have different Name Servers, C Class, and Whois Information?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you will find that CDN's will give you a dedicated IP address for each container you setup, however they will share the same C Class IP address depending on where the content has been downloaded from as CDN's work by closest region so you generally get more than 1 IP address per a region.

So with this said you will get a dedicated IP address but will share the same C class, now the other thing is you will get the same TLD i.e `your-container-id.cf3.rackcdn.com` So the foot prints here are the C class IP and the TLD domain. If you are daisy chaining the sites with one another and you have gone to the extent to have different C Class IP addresses and you believe that Google uses this in their algorithm then yes, it leaves a footprint.

It should be possible to speed up your site(s) without CDN with decent hosting if you are concerned about Google.

Answer (score 0):

I actually work at Incapsula.

To answer your question:

1. All of our IP ranges were manually submitted to Google. As a result, when you use Incapsula, Google will know that this is a CDN reverse proxy.
2. Incapsula IPs are used by highly trusted sites/organizations. 
   Consider the Trust benefits of having the same range as large government sites and Fortune 500 companies.... From what I saw, sites that use relatively low trust IPs (i.e. tier 2-3 share hosts) will actually get a very nice SEO boost just by onboarding Incapsula.

For further reference I've added here 2 links to a blog posts I wrote about CDN related SEO benefits and common SEO related myths:

SEO Benefits: http://www.incapsula.com/the-incapsu...and-advantages

SEO Myths: http://www.incapsula.com/the-incapsu...s-myth-busting

GL

PS: I also just answered a similar question in WarriorForum.